# Error while merging two pandas dataframes together on the index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two pandas dataframes together on index but i am getting error...

## Here is df1

```
      alleles  chrom  pos strand  assembly#  center  protLSID  assayLSID  
rs#
TP121     C/A      0  121      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP135     G/A      0  135      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP283     A/G      0  283      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP302     C/T      0  302      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP334     T/G      0  334      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
```

## Here is the df2

```
      1KS 2861 2862 2A 2KS 3KS 4KS 5B 5C A1  ...  WWA17replicate WWA18 WWA21  
rs#                                          ...
TP121   N    N    N  N   N   N   N  N  N  N  ...               N     N     N
TP135   N    N    G  N   N   N   N  N  N  N  ...               N     N     N
TP283   A    N    N  N   A   A   N  R  N  A  ...               N     N     N
TP302   C    C    N  Y   C   N   C  Y  Y  T  ...               Y     N     N
TP334   G    N    N  N   N   N   N  N  N  N  ...               N     N     N
```

When i try to merge, i get this error - `"['TP121' 'TP135' 'TP283' ..., 'TP251072' 'TP251178' 'TP251355'] not in index"` when they are clearly in both the indexes. Where am i doing wrong?

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df.index, how = "outer")
```

Comment: As of 2021 I am getting similar error. The column name to join on is clearly in both dataframes, but if refuses to proceed, since the error message states the name of this collumn in the end of the error message as if it was not present. My pandas version is 1.1.5. Does anyone knows wether it is a bug in merge function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather try:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Well that worked really well. Wonder why the merge didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For your task `pd.concat` is better then merge. But with `merge` you could merge two dataframe with `reset_index` on column `rs#`:

```
pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on='rs#')
```

If you'll need resulted dataframe to have the original index you could use then `set_index`:

```
pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on='rs#').set_index('rs#')

In [50]: df1
Out[50]: 
      alleles  chrom  pos strand  assembly#  center  protLSID  assayLSID
rs#                                                                     
TP121     C/A      0  121      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP135     G/A      0  135      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP283     A/G      0  283      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP302     C/T      0  302      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN
TP334     T/G      0  334      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN

In [51]: df2
Out[51]: 
      1KS 2861 2862 2A 2KS 3KS 4KS 5B 5C A1 WWA17replicate WWA18 WWA21
rs#                                                                   
TP121   N    N    N  N   N   N   N  N  N  N              N     N     N
TP135   N    N    G  N   N   N   N  N  N  N              N     N     N
TP283   A    N    N  N   A   A   N  R  N  A              N     N     N
TP302   C    C    N  Y   C   N   C  Y  Y  T              Y     N     N
TP334   G    N    N  N   N   N   N  N  N  N              N     N     N

In [52]: pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on='rs#').set_index('rs#')
Out[52]: 
      alleles  chrom  pos strand  assembly#  center  protLSID  assayLSID 1KS  \
rs#                                                                            
TP121     C/A      0  121      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN   N   
TP135     G/A      0  135      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN   N   
TP283     A/G      0  283      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN   A   
TP302     C/T      0  302      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN   C   
TP334     T/G      0  334      +        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN   G   

      2861  ...  2A 2KS 3KS 4KS 5B 5C A1 WWA17replicate WWA18 WWA21  
rs#         ...                                                      
TP121    N  ...   N   N   N   N  N  N  N              N     N     N  
TP135    N  ...   N   N   N   N  N  N  N              N     N     N  
TP283    N  ...   N   A   A   N  R  N  A              N     N     N  
TP302    C  ...   Y   C   N   C  Y  Y  T              Y     N     N  
TP334    N  ...   N   N   N   N  N  N  N              N     N     N  

[5 rows x 21 columns]
```